# How to create rule that allow update only that value that is bigger than 0 in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I would like to create a rule for my database in the firestore that does not allow updating items to a value less than 0.

Data structure collection - users - document id (random) - value name online. users/docID/{online: 0, etc..}

I try something like this but it doesn't work. How to do this right?

Dart code that is responsible for update

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(docID).updateData({
            'online' : FieldValue.increment(-10.0)
          });
```

Security code

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
    match /users/{user} {
        allow update: if request.resource.data.online > 0
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you pls show 1/ Your entire security rules 2/The code used to update ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure?authuser=0#overlapping_match_statements), "In the case where multiple allow expressions match a request, the access is allowed if **any** of the conditions is true."

In your case, `match /{document=**}` and `match /users/{user}` actually overlap therefore any update is authorized, because the rule for `match /{document=**}` is `allow read, write;`

The following should do the trick:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{user} {
        allow read: ....;
        allow create: ....;
        allow delete: ....;
        allow update: if request.resource.data.online > 0;
      }
  }
}
```